# Procedural Macros for custom operator of T in Rust

Tags: rust

Basically, I want to implement custom operator in Rust.

One is pipeline-operator that is on `T`.

[operator overloading](https://doc.rust-lang.org/rust-by-example/trait/ops.html) only works for local structures so not usable for type `T`.

On the other hand, [`apply::Apply`](https://docs.rs/apply/0.3.0/apply/trait.Apply.html) does work on `T`

```
/// Represents a type which can have functions applied to it (implemented
/// by default for all types).
pub trait Apply<Res> {
    /// Apply a function which takes the parameter by value.
    fn apply<F: FnOnce(Self) -> Res>(self, f: F) -> Res
    where Self: Sized {
        f(self)
    }
}

impl<T: ?Sized, Res> Apply<Res> for T {
    // use default definitions...
}
```

```rust
let string = 1.apply(|x| x * 2).apply(|x: i32| x.to_string());
```

However, I don't like this `.apply` syntax. It's the same as Prototype Pollution in JavaScript and can collide with `some-structure.apply`

In any case, I prefer binary operator like

```rust
let string = 1 |> (|x| x * 2) |> (|x: i32| x.to_string());
```

So my question is:

Writing the code above with a binary operator such as `|>`, is it possible to transpile the code (Macro input) to something (Macro output) like

```rust
let string = 1.myownapply(|x| x * 2).myownapply(|x: i32| x.to_string());
```

`myownapply` can be a much longer strings to avoid the collision.

I've read [Procedural Macros](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/procedural-macros.html) in Rust can do anything, so is this possible?
If this is not so hard, I appreciate if you provide a sample code.

Answer (score 0):

This should be possible with `macro_rules!`, see https://doc.rust-lang.org/rust-by-example/macros.html and https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/macros-by-example.html. Try something like this:

```
macro_rules! pipeline {
    ($expr:expr $(=> $func:expr)+) => {
        $expr $(.apply($func))+
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, could you add a code to show how to use for instance. I know this is Declarative macro  and I think Procedural Macros is still required here for cleaner usage.